# Numeros enteros en pandas python "dataframe"

Tags: python, pandas, bigdecimal, números-enteros

Importo un documento a jupiter e ingresa normal con numeros enteros, aplico una fórmula para agrupar, sumar y luego restar y el producto salen todos los números con decimales y exponenciales.

¿Cómo obtengo sólo números enteros???

::::::: adjunto código ::::::::::

```
mydataset_df.head(10)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
cond1_df = (
    mydataset_df
    .groupby(["move_id/id"], as_index=False)
    .sum()
    .assign(
        balance=lambda row: row.credit - row.debit
    )
    .assign(
        resultado=lambda row: row.balance < -0.000001
    )

)

cond1_df.head()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yan no entiendo muy bién cual es el problema, es solo un tema de representación, tus columnas `credit` y `debit` originalmente son floats no enteros. Si sabes que esas columnas continen y van a contener solo enteros  parsealas con este tipo al cargar el df original. Puedes suprimir la notación científica si quieres, pero no es un problema en si mismo.

Comment: y como suprimo la notacion cientifica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las columnas originalmente son de tipo float, el uso de la notación científica se usa por defecto para mostrar valores muy grandes o muy pequeños para poder representar el DataFrame en el siempre limitado espacio de pantalla sin tener columnas excesivamente anchas.

Un ejemplo muy sencillo:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1214514552.0, 14455145556552.0]})

>>> df
              A
0  1.214515e+09
1  1.445515e+13
```

Se puede forzar un determinado formato a la hora de representar los floats mediante la opción `display.float_format` y usando el [*format specification mini language*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) de Python:

```
>>> pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{.1f}'.format)
>>> df
                 A
0     1214514552.0
1 14455145556552.0
```

También puedes usar `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}'.format`.

En este caso con `:.1f` fuerza a que se muestren los floats con un solo decimal. **Esto no afecta en nada a los datos en sí**, solo a la forma en la que se muestran.

Comment: Excelente, gracias!!!